# What is the exact meaning of "wave motion"?

Tags: waves, definition

What does wave motion mean? My textbooks talk about wave motion but never defines it. Then some internet searches confused me more. In words how do you define wave motion?

Comment: If you want the general equation of a transverse wave, it is ∂^2y/∂t^2 = v^2 ∂^2y/∂x^2. v is velocity of wave.

Comment: I need to know the definition of "wave motion" in words.

Comment: Like water moving due to a passing ship ? Or a lower E guitar string - detune it to go to low frequency?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In words, wave motion is the direction that the energy of a wave moves.  An everyday example is an ocean wave. The magnitude of the up and down motion of a wave off the shore is an indication of how much energy the wave has. The movement of that up and down motion towards the shore is the direction of travel of the energy. When it crashes on the shore the energy is dissipated.

Hope this helps

Comment: A standing wave also exhibits wave motion.

Comment: @my2cts yes but constructive (and destructive) interference involves the motion of more than one wave. The OP is asking about the motion of a wave. I wanted to keep it simple.

Comment: Thank you that helps!